# How to Write a Variable for a Pie Chart with Multiple Fields in Qlik Sense

Tags: variables, qliksense

I am looking for some help in regards to writing a variable for a Pie Chart on my dashboard. I currently have the following variable for a KPI chart and this shows the latest weeks value but has the flexibility to change if a different week is selected.

```
=Sum({<week_date ={">=$(=Weekstart(max(week_date)))<=$(=Weekend(max(week_date)))"}>}total_calls)
```

Now for my pie chart, I want to show the different type of work that has been worked on during the week and this is through the 'source' column which has the following types. This will be my dimension(slice).

```
SOURCE
Calls
Email
Offline
```

The measure will show the number of 'touches' and is then displayed as a %. This works if I put the fields in, but I would like to write a variable so that it is dynamic but not sure how I do that.

Would appreciate any advice on how to move this forward.

---

UPDATES

I have the following values for the latest week (week ending) 21/02/2020:

Calls  | 8,477
Email | 4,040
Offline | 9,052

and would like to show this in a Pie Chart. Currently I have managed to write the following definition:

```
=Sum({<[w_c.week_date] ={">=$(=Weekstart(max([w_c.week_date])))<=$(=Weekend(max([w_c.week_date])))"}>}[w_c.touches])
```

but I get a total instead of the individual sums for the Sources even though I have selected the SOURCE as the DIMENSION.

SOURCE | $(vVariable)
Calls  | 21,569
Email | 21, 569
Offline | 21,569

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

---

I have added my table view as well as how I am able to get the figures manually if I select the source and week_date column as the dimension and the touches as the measure. If I filter for the latest week it shows me the volumes I want, but I would like this to work dynamically through the use of a variable. I have attached an image showing this, numbers will be different to the above as these have been updated.[image: data manager]

[image: data_manager]

Comment: Possible to show some examples? Not sure i can understand the issue

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks for your response. Will update my initial question with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this by removing the "=" from my expression and this gave me the correct individual figures.

```
=Sum({<[w_c.week_date] =
```

to

```
Sum({<[w_c.week_date] = ...
```